# What does the "IO Error: Socket read timed out" means (SQL developer)

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I try to open SQL developer then I am getting this error:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
IO Error: Socket read timed out
The Network Adapter could not establish the connection Vendor code 17002
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I had a system that was working fine, than suddenly I had this issue. My solution? Restart the notebook...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typical causes for that error:

1. Your database listener is not running
2. It is running, but maybe there is a firewall intervening
3. It is running, no firewall issue, but you have provided incorrect connection details.

Source: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3519434

Comment: To check for 1., enter `lsnrctl SERVICES LISTENER` at the command prompt (add your listener name if not using the default).

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure your installation is on a LOCAL drive!**

If your SQL Developer is launched from a network location (specifically, a different location than your database network location), that *could* be the issue.

I was having the same problem and **I moved my installation to my local drive** and it connected right away :)

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are exact causes but to resolve this:

Go to server machine and login as root then run:

```
( # xhost + )
```

Then come to oracle user and run:

```
( $ lsnrctl reload LISTENER_NAME )
```